# strange behaviour when using mutex in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

While investigating some scenario's in C++ (11) regarding multithreading, I ran into this strange (to me) situation.

I'm running the `increment` function below in 2 threads, passing in the address of a shared variable. The core code is this:

```
static std::mutex mtx;

static void increment(int *x, int nofIncrements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nofIncrements; i++)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        (*x)++;
        mtx.unlock();
    }
}
```

As you can see a mutex is used to lock the increment operation (inefficient, I know the right solution is to use atomic but I'm trying to understand what's going on).

This code is run in 2 threads with a value for `nofIncrements = 100000`, which means that I expect the final value to be `200000`. However, sometimes I get `200001` which I can't explain...

The full class (available in this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d218dce2a43a06abe6a):

```
class LockedIncrement
{
    int _nofIncrements;
    int _counter;

    static std::mutex mtx;

    static void increment(int *x, int nofIncrements)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nofIncrements; i++)
        {
            mtx.lock();
            (*x)++;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }

public:

    LockedIncrement(int nofIncrements)
    {
        _nofIncrements = nofIncrements;
    }

    void DoTest()
    {
        std::thread t1(increment, &_counter, _nofIncrements);
        std::thread t2(increment, &_counter, _nofIncrements);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        std::cout << "Counter = " << _counter << " (expected " << 2 * _nofIncrements << ")\n";
    }
};
```

The test can be run like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto nofIncrements = 1000000;
    std::cout << "locked increment \n\n";
    auto test = LockedIncrement(nofIncrements);
    test.DoTest();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using appropriate [std::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) mechanisms in 1st place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code from gist increments `_counter` which is not initialized, this is leading to undetermined behaviour. You are lucky to get 200000 and 200001...I'm getting 377232...

```
LockedIncrement(int nofIncrements) : 
    _nofIncrements( nofIncrements ), 
    _counter ( 0 )
{
}
```

Comment: argh, of course. Strange though that it is apparently initialized to either 0 or 1 in my case. The definition of 'undefined', I guess. Thanks.